# Facing problem to text-indent second and further lines

Tags: javascript, html, text

I am using HTML code in .js file shown below :

```
$("#lineItemReview").append("<p style=\"text-indent : 3em; line-height: 1.0;\">SO: " + $("#inputOrderNumber" + i).val() + "</p>");
    
$("#lineItemReview").append("<p style=\"text-indent : 3em; line-height: 1.0;\">PO: " + $("#inputPurchaseOrderNum" + i).val()+"</p>");
```

And these above information are printing on pop-up dialog box with some specific width and height.

I am facing problem when text get longer means when same text comes on next line its not following text-indent style that has been specified already in above code.

**For Example :**

**Its coming like this :**

[image]

**BUT, I want like this :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using margin/padding instead.

```
$("#lineItemReview").append("<p style=\"margin-left: 3em; line-height: 1.0;\">SO: " + $("#inputOrderNumber" + i).val() + "</p>");
    
$("#lineItemReview").append("<p style=\"margin-left: 3em; line-height: 1.0;\">PO: " + $("#inputPurchaseOrderNum" + i).val()+"</p>");
```

Comment: Thanks Gijs. Its Really working . Thanks a lot man